# Do I have to sign all the jars?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

I got a situation. I need to sign all the RIA (Applets and webstart).

As per my knowledge I need to sign all the jars that contains the classes which extends Applet or JApplet. i have following question.

Suppose there are classes structure as below:

- `XClass` extends JApplet/Applet

  - `YClass` extends `XClass`.

So should I have to sign all the jars that contains `XClass` or `YClass` or should I sign only the jars that contains `XClass` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to sign all the jars?

Yes.  A security bug might be exploited by any of them, and that is what Oracle is trying to prevent.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Are you sure ? do you face similar problem ?

Comment: Hello Andrew i found some point from googling. Be certain to sign all JAR files 
used by your Java applet. If you sign the JAR file with your main applet class, 
your applet will launch. If it later uses classes from another JAR file, though, 
you can run into trouble. If the newly-loaded class tries a restricted operation 
and its JAR file isn't signed, your applet will fail at that point with a 
security exception. Is it correct ? Should i need to sign all the jars ?

Comment: *"Hello Andrew i found some point from googling."*  The net is a big place.  Provide a link to the information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303644/signing-my-jar-files. Check the answer section

Comment: Wow.  nIcE cOw  usually does a much better job of answering questions. :(  Not only is that poorly formatted, but it doesn't link back to the source.  Further, a Google search on that first paragraph fails to show a top hit at Oracle, or any official Oracle site.  So I would have been suspicious of the information when it was written.  Not only that, but security bugs cropped up since then that tightened security more than it had been ever before.  So my view is that the information, wherever it came from is out of date and irrelevant.  **Sign - *all* - Jars.**

Comment: So i should sign the jars that extends JApplet\Applet only. Correct ?

Comment: `<head-desk />`  Which part of ***ALL*** are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I got the info from your reply that all the jars not required to be signed. But the last " Sign - all -Jars" confusing a bit, so i raised the question just for confirmation. i am glad you are here. i really appreciate your depth on this topic.